# Analytic function $f'(a) = f(a)$ implies $f$ is the exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, analytic-functions

> Let $f$ be an analytic function on the disc $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \; |\; |z| < 1\}$ satisfying $f(0) = 1$. Is the following statement true or false? If $f'(a) = f(a)$ whenever $\frac{1+a}{a}$ and $\frac{1−a}{a}$ are prime numbers, then $f(z) = e^z \; \forall z \in D$.

I have tried to write out the power series of both $f$ and $f'$ and matching them term by term. What is the point of the two prime numbers in this question? Thanks.

Comment: If you have $\frac {1+a}a=\frac 1a+1=p_1$ and $\frac {1-a}a=\frac 1a-1=p_2$ then $p_1,p_2$ are twin primes and for all we know there might be only finitely many of these.

Comment: This looks like a Bourbaki-lite joke restatement of the twin-prime conjecture as @lulu noticed, the $a$'s correspond to twin primes and $a_n \to 0$ if the $p,p+2 \to \infty$, so if there are infinitely many such, one has $f'-f=0$ by identity so $f(z)=e^z$ by the initial condition so problem true, while if there only finitely many twin primes hence $a_1,...a_k$, one can use $f(z)=C(z-a_1)^2...(z-a_k)^2$ with $C$ chosen so $f(0)=1$, hence the problem is false